# Update UI WinForms with multiple tasks

Tags: c#, winforms, task

I've a basic form application. It displays a list of checkbox and a list of asyn task update CheckBox label :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<CheckBox> checkedBoxes = new List<CheckBox>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CreateCheckBoxes();
        Display();
    }

   public void CreateCheckBoxes()
    {

        SuspendLayout();
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        {
            checkedBoxes.Add(new CheckBox() {Name = "Combo"+i, Text = "-"+i  });

            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(checkedBoxes[i]);
        }
        ResumeLayout();
    }


    private async void Display()
    {

        List < Task < LyStruc >> tasks = new List<Task<LyStruc>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => { return ProcessMessage(i); }) );
        }

        var wa =  await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());

        // Doesn't work (few checkbox update label)
        foreach (LyStruc t in wa)
        {
            UpdateCheckBoxLabel(t);
        }

        // Doesn't work either.
        //TaskScheduler taskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
        //foreach (var item in tasks)
        //{
        //    item.ContinueWith(c =>
        //    {
        //        switch (c.Status)
        //        {
        //            case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion: Test(c.Result); break;
        //            case TaskStatus.Faulted: richTextBox1.Text = c.Exception.ToString(); break;
        //        }

        //    }, taskScheduler);
        // }
    }

    private void UpdateCheckBoxLabel(LyStruc s)
    {
        this.checkedBoxes[s.Id].Text = "Update" + s.Name;   
    }


    private LyStruc ProcessMessage(int i)
    {
        return new LyStruc()
        {
            Id = i,
            Name = string.Format( "-Combo {0}", i),
        };
    }

}
```

Why don't all checkboxes change (just few of them)  ? I get no errors. I expect that each check box update with label CheckBox

Comment: I don't see any code where you set `LyStruc.Id`

Comment: Indeed, i delete this line of code in my request by error. Example is up to date. Regards